# Simulate shift key press depending on preceding text

Tags: key-bindings, capitalization

When writing text, I would like not to have to press "Shift" when, say, the preceding text is a sentence end (e.g., `".  "`).

So, for example, if I have written `Hi.` and then I type `b`, a `B` should appear on the buffer.

I imagine this could be done by advising `self-insert-command` or `expand-abbrev`.

It is important that the solution works well with abbreviations.  So, if `b` is expanded into "bye", then typing `b` in the previous example should expand into `Bye`.

I don't want to use the `auto-capitalize` package, as it is noticeably slow and sometimes incompatible with other packages.

Comment: Modifying `self-insert-command` will most likely not end well, however, there's a hook that runs after this function is called: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Keymaps-and-Minor-Modes.html . But I have to confess, I don't know in what order does Emacs call this hook related to abbrev expansion, and whether this hook is called after the expansion.

Comment: I had success by re-binding keys 'a'-'z' to my own self-insert-command which checks whether to upcase or not the `last-command-event` and then calls interactively the normal self-insert-command.